# Bitbucket pipeline err

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

getting the below error in my pipeline. Can anyone help me on this ?
Am trying the deploy my ecs service via bitbucket pipelines but facing this error. I tried updating docker, pip, docker-compose everything but no luck

current versions:
docker-compose: 1.29.2
pip: 23.3.1
docker: latest

**My yaml file code**:

````
          name: "Deployment"
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - node
            - docker
          script:
            - pip install awscli docker-compose
            - docker-compose --version
            - aws configure set aws_access_key "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}"
            - aws configure set aws_secret_key "${AWS_SECRET_KEY}"
            - docker-compose -f ./docker/docker-compose.stg.yml build
            - eval $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1 | sed 's;https://;;g')
            - docker push ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}/dashboard-service:stg
            - aws ecs update-service --cluster new-services --service dashboard-service --force-new-deployment```

**ERROR CODE:**
+ docker-compose -f ./docker/docker-compose.stg.yml build
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 8, in \<module\>
  sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 81, in main
  command_func()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 200, in perform_command
  project = project_from_options('.', options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 60, in project_from_options
  return get_project(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/command.py", line 152, in get_project
  client = get_client(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client
  client = docker_client(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 124, in docker_client
***  kwargs = kwargs_from_env(environment=environment, ssl_version=tls_version)
  TypeError: kwargs_from_env() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_version'***
````

Answer (score 3):

The `ssl_version` parameter is removed in the [docker 7.0.0](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/change-log.html) package because it uses TLSv1.3 by default.

Add constraint to your requirements like "docker<7" as a quick solution.

Comment: Works well, and with link to the source. Very nice, thank you!

Comment: @Sebastian How or where did you manage to specify the docker version < 7 or so? I have similar script to what's posted in the question.

Comment: @Basil right next to docker-compose in the `pip install` call, the pull request is https://github.com/hartwork/wnpp.debian.net/pull/874 .

Answer (score 1):

It seems after the update of bitbucket over the weekend - you might be using a newer version of docker without knowing it. Here is what works ok for me:

```
image: docker:23.0.5

options:
  docker: true

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build-test
        name: Build and test
        max-time: 10
        caches:
          - docker
        script:
          - export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
          - docker compose -f ./docker/docker-compose.stg.yml build
```

Now Docker supports `docker compose` so no need to install and use `docker-compose` anymore

Comment: _Sad buildkit noises_ but this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: `docker-compose` is Python and version 1.x while `docker compose` is Golang and version 2.x. The question above is about Python and version 1.x. Upgrading to 2.x may or may not be an option.

Comment: Compose V1 is deadware, any further use is discouraged. If you can't opt into Compose V2, you have a problem.

Comment: I was using docker:stable so that updated my docker version and docker-compose was not an option anymore. I switched into explicit version of docker to avoid future problems, so that might be causing issue to some people, too

Answer (score 1):

we figured out the issue.

Docker has release latest version as "7.0" which is not supported in bitbucket. So after install docker-compose forcefully install docker 6.1.3 version.

```
- pip install awscli docker-compose            
- pip install docker==6.1.3
```

Comment: How is docker (the-python-library) unsupported in bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

---

Refer to this article:

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-docker-images-as-build-environments/

```
image:
  name: atlassian/default-image:3
```

Comment: it's there in code, removed while pasting

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).